# undefined variable when defined for model

Tags: yii

My actionCreate and actionUpdate looks quite similar. This works fine with my actionCreate, but my actionUpdate is not seeing the declared variable. `Undefined variable: attr`

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);
        $attr = new ProductAttribute();
        if(isset($_POST['Product']))
        {
            $model->update_date = time();
            $model->product_approval_status = "N";
     //blah blah blah all about this product model
        }
        //attributes here
        $valid = true;
        $arrAttrData = array();
        if($model->save()){
            if(isset($_POST['ProductAttribute'])){
                foreach($_POST['ProductAttribute'] as $i=>$attrItem){
                    $attr = new ProductAttribute;
                    $attr->attributes = $attrItem;
                    if ( $model->product_id )
                        $attr->product_id = $model->product_id;
                    if ( $attr->validate() )
                        $attr->save();
                }
            }
            unset($attr);
        }
        $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'attr'=>$attr
    ));
}
```

Comment: Because your are unsetting it? `unset($attr);`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should remove the line

```
unset($attr);
```